# .htaccess, mod_rewrite, and basic authentication

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I am working on a Wordpress site, and my pages are using a permalink structure that mod_rewrites them to look like directories. For a few pages I want to use Basic Authentication to password protect a few of the pages. How would I write this in my .htaccess file? Am I protecting the file, or the rewritten address?

Comment: The only thing that came close to being successful is, I made a directory named the same as the friendly URL (i.e. /friendlyurl/) and put an .htaccess file in there requesting authentication. Going to the page, I was asked for credentials and then sent to a 403 Forbidden error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't need mod_rewrite for this, hopefully, this should do the trick:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/some/path/to/protect require_auth=true
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/another/protected/path require_auth=true

# Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

# Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from everyone
Deny from all
# except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any
# 1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user
# or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```

The mod_auth and mod_env modules *should* have precidence over mod_rewrite, so your fake directory structure should stay the same. You'd just need to fill out a `SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI ^/some/path/to/protect require_auth=true` for each one, then fill out the rest of the auth stuff to suit your needs.

Comment: Well, I don't completely understand why that did it, but… that did it! Thank you so much! I was sweating this for half of the day!

Comment: @Imaginary Essentially, if the `require_auth` environment variable is *not* set, there is no need for authentication. The `SetEnvIfNoCase` directives at the top sets that variable if the request is for certain directories (whether they exist or not).

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I have with this solution is that clicking the cancel button will show the protected page. I tried to solve this by using:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} !user
RewriteRule ^/protected-page /unauthenticated-page [R=401]
```

But that didn't work. I'm not sure why.

To solve the problem quick and dirty I added

```
ErrorDocument 401 "You don't have access."
```

To create a redirect I used this

```
ErrorDocument 401 '<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=/unauthenticated-page" /></head><body></body></html>'
```

Comment: The dirty trick works, Cpanel was giving me headaches for the last week...

Answer (score 1):

For those who came here with same problem as me, with .htaccess like this

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "some_name"
AuthUserFile "/path/to/password/passwd"
require valid-user
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

rules above are not working as I expected (authorize, then rewrite)

> because of directive merging order ("If" is merged last)

thanks to [comment from Alek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/apache-htaccess-redirect-to-https-before-asking-for-user-authentication#comment-42210075) to point that out

so when I removed IfModule brackets, the rules have begun to work for me.