# Password protect a virtual directory? - .htpasswd/.htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtual-directory, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

Is it possible to password protect a virtual directory (such as a wordpress category):

```
/c/sofas/
```

It looks like `<Location /c/sofas/>` would work in httpd_config, but not .htaccess

Is it possible? Possibly with a mod_rewrite somewhere?

Comment: AFAIK no, but it wouldn't really make sense, either - seeing as an attacker could simply figure out the real URL behind the rewritten one, and access that. (Perhaps if you edit in your exact use case, somebody can come up with an alternative solution)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203989/htaccess-mod-rewrite-and-basic-authentication

Comment: Pekka -- the example below is a perfect example, which James Holwell also linked to.

It's in a WordPress-like system -- there is no way they can access the content accept on that URL.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately `<Location>` directive isn't allowed in `.htaccess`.

**But there is an alternate neat solution using [`mod_setenvif`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html)**.

```
# set env variable SECURED if current URI is /c/sofas/
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/c/sofas/" SECURED

# invoke basic auth is SECURED is set
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /full/path/to/passwords
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      allow,deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=SECURED
```

Comment: I was just alerted that there's a strange bug. If you hit "Cancel" it still loads the page. Do you know anyway to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Ok let me try to reproduce it.

Comment: Sorry I had the `allow,deny` reversed. Try it now.

Comment: Working now, thanks! I should really read more about the area.

Comment: Spoke to soon -- it applied it to the whole website.

Comment: I have tested it again and again and didn't find any problem. Auth dialog is shown only for a particular `/c/sofas/` URLs.

Comment: I am guessing it has to do with something else -- this still seems to be the right answer. Thank you