# Adding comments to .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, comments

Why does this work:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1
```

and this work:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 [L] #bla bla bla
```

but this doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule (.+)/$ $1 #bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 164, accepted):

#### Comments in .htaccess must be on their *own line*, not appended to other statements.

The last rule doesn't work because the comments aren't really comments. Comments in htaccess *must begin* with a `#` (must be at the start of a line), and not arbitrarily anywhere.

In the second case, the `#bla bla bla` is interpreted as a 4th parameter of the `RewriteRule` directive, which is simply ignored.

In the last case, the `#bla bla bla` is interpreted as a 3rd parameter, which in the `RewriteRule`'s case is where the flags go, and `#bla bla bla` isn't any flags that mod_rewrite understands so you get an error.

Comment: Can comments be inside a <IfModule> ?

Comment: While `#` must be at the "start" of the line, it can be preceded by any amount of whitespace.  (Excess) Whitespace in .htaccess is ignored, and can be "sprinkled" anywhere, including at the beginning of lines.  In other words, `#` must be the first non-whitespace character on a line. I erroneously used to think `#` had to be character 1, in the left-most column!

Answer (score 28):

Apache's config file format (of which `.htaccess` files are one example) doesn't technically support inline comments, only full-line comments (i.e. a line *beginning* with a `#`).

> Lines that begin with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored. Comments may not be included on a line after a configuration directive. -- [Official Apache 2.4 manual](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html)

Confusingly, though, each module gets to parse the input for its directives however it likes - so `mod_rewrite` decides what to do with any line beginning with `RewriteRule`

I don't know for sure but my guess is that `mod_rewrite` is ignoring everything after the `[flags]`, and the `#` isn't actually necessary at all.

Best bet, though, is to always keep comments to their own line, since that will work whatever the directive you're commenting.