# .htaccess causes ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using shared hosting (apache, php, wordpress) and while trying to prevent access to .htaccess and wp-config I'm getting

> ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

what I did is putting these into the .htaccess:

```
# protect the wp-config file
<files wp-config.php> 
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</files> 

# Prevent access to .htaccess
<Files .htaccess>
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

That's all there is in my .htaccess.
I followed the examples in most websites that show this.
If I sweep the order:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

There is no internal error, but this is not what I saw in most websites guides.
If someone know why and what to use.

Comment: 500/internal errors are always accompanied by a more detailed message in the webservers `error.log`.

Comment: No log. there was, I delete it and made another call to my website- nothing there (same root at .htaccess)

Comment: [Why is there a space between "#" and "words" ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106873/adding-comments-to-htaccess)

Answer (score 7):

Is this on an Apache 2.2 or an Apache 2.4 server? The Order/Deny rules have changed in Apache 2.4, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html

If it is Apache 2.4, then the two lines:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

are to be replaced with:

```
Require all denied
```

Alternatively, if it is a server you own, you can also enable the [`mod_access_compat`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_access_compat.html) module, which is a compatibility module for 2.4 to support 2.2 configurations. But since it is a shared hosting, I doubt you can do that, unless you ask them nicely.

Comment: After a bit of Googling, I found that nginx does not use .htaccess. You may want to google for "WordPress on nginx" to find out how to configure your WP to run on Nginx.
See e.g.: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx

You may also want to remove the apache tag from your question.

Comment: I checked now with Hostgator, it is Apache 2.2.24 or 2.2.25. so I was wrong, it is not nginx (I got from builtwith.com)

Answer (score 1):

Update:
the problem was caused by a space character between the words: allow, deny.

**Order allow, deny**