# CakePHP htaccess settings for GoDaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I have the following right now

**/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

**/app/webroot/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Error**

> Am getting a blank page when i go to the root.

**Error Log**

```
[Sat Sep 26 00:23:15.505891 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663691929344] [client 66.249.79.212:42495] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:23:15.505877 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663691929344] [client 66.249.79.212:42495] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:23:15.505827 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663691929344] [client 66.249.79.212:42495] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:45.438750 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139664010061568] [client 122.172.26.161:55610] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:45.438741 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139664010061568] [client 122.172.26.161:55610] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:45.438706 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139664010061568] [client 122.172.26.161:55610] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.965029 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 619898:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55609] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.965011 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 619898:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55609] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.964968 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 619898:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55609] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.107687 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 613992:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55608] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.107677 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 613992:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55608] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:44.107640 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 613992:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55608] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.912155 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663870256896] [client 122.172.26.161:55607] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.912140 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663870256896] [client 122.172.26.161:55607] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.912110 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663870256896] [client 122.172.26.161:55607] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.533245 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55606] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.533236 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55606] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:43.533206 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614267:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55606] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:42.886605 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614311:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55604] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:42.886596 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614311:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55604] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:42.886559 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614311:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55604] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:41.815606 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55603] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:41.815587 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55603] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:41.815546 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663712909056] [client 122.172.26.161:55603] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:40.454857 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614542:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55601] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:40.454848 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614542:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55601] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:22:40.454805 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614542:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55601] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:54.627365 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614670:tid 139663733888768] [client 122.172.26.161:55560] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:54.627347 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614670:tid 139663733888768] [client 122.172.26.161:55560] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:54.627311 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614670:tid 139663733888768] [client 122.172.26.161:55560] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:34.925130 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663796827904] [client 122.172.26.161:55543] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:34.925110 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663796827904] [client 122.172.26.161:55543] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:34.925060 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614907:tid 139663796827904] [client 122.172.26.161:55543] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:27.980008 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55538] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:27.979999 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55538] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:21:27.979967 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614610:tid 139663681439488] [client 122.172.26.161:55538] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:59.747367 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614828:tid 139663968102144] [client 122.172.26.161:55445] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:59.747352 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614828:tid 139663968102144] [client 122.172.26.161:55445] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:59.747317 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614828:tid 139663968102144] [client 122.172.26.161:55445] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:14.919864 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614221:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55416] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:14.919854 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614221:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55416] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:14.919820 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614221:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:55416] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:12.514216 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614806:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55415] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:12.514207 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614806:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55415] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Sat Sep 26 00:18:12.514169 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 614806:tid 139663744378624] [client 122.172.26.161:55415] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:46:16.690477 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587680:tid 139663807317760] [client 122.172.26.161:54223] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:46:16.675899 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587680:tid 139663807317760] [client 122.172.26.161:54223] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:46:16.675853 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587680:tid 139663807317760] [client 122.172.26.161:54223] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.203490 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587034:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:54035] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.203467 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587034:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:54035] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.188255 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587034:tid 139663838787328] [client 122.172.26.161:54035] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.093514 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 586970:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54034] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.093482 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 586970:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54034] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:12.078451 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 586970:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54034] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.672487 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587202:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54033] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.672466 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587202:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54033] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.658764 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587202:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54033] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.558489 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587407:tid 139663859767040] [client 122.172.26.161:54032] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.558468 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587407:tid 139663859767040] [client 122.172.26.161:54032] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:11.547781 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587407:tid 139663859767040] [client 122.172.26.161:54032] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:09.981467 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587772:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54030] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:09.981455 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587772:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54030] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:09.970972 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 587772:tid 139663828297472] [client 122.172.26.161:54030] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:08.462473 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 589099:tid 139663817807616] [client 122.172.26.161:54028] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ErrorHandler' not found in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 916
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:08.462457 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 589099:tid 139663817807616] [client 122.172.26.161:54028] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include() [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/archangle1973/public_html/lib:.:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/pear:/opt/alt/php53/usr/share/php') in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
[Fri Sep 25 23:41:08.462409 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 589099:tid 139663817807616] [client 122.172.26.161:54028] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  include(/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/archangle1973/public_html/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 545
```

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is on and instead of RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] use RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L]

Comment: doesnt seem to work. ..can you please explain why we need to change that?

Comment: yes. I am assuming you want to redirect anything eg. www.mysite.com/page1 to www.mysite.com/index.php/page1. The regex ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1  does just that

Comment: @SNAG which is not what CakePHP uses.

Comment: `Failed opening '/home/m7play/archangle.mink7.com/lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php` Is that a valid path on your development machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Refer to the documentation

The [docs for the current version of CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html#apache) have a specific mention for godaddy. Whilst it's obvious you're not using the current version, the docs are still relevant (emphasis added):

> For many hosting services (GoDaddy, 1and1), your web server is actually being served from a user directory that already uses mod_rewrite. If you are installing CakePHP into a user directory (`http://example.com/~username/cakephp/`), or any other URL structure that already utilizes mod_rewrite, you’ll need to **add RewriteBase statements to the .htaccess files** CakePHP uses (.htaccess, webroot/.htaccess).

Example webroot htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # v add this
    RewriteBase /path/to/app 
    # ^ add this
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The details of those changes will depend on your setup, and can include additional things that are not related to CakePHP. Please refer to Apache’s online documentation for more information. If you are still having problems you'll need to [find out how to access the error log](https://www.godaddy.com/help/working-with-error-logs-1197), read the error message and modify your setup appropriately.

Comment: added this `RewriteBase /home/archangle1973/public_html/app # <- add this` but still nothing happens. Updated the error logs

Comment: now getting this error `RewriteBase takes one argument, the base URL of the per-directory context`

Comment: "takes one argument" indicates it's getting more than one argument - it's not interpreting the comment as a comment. Seems apache's comment handling [isn't consistent](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22107059/761202) - but you already searched/thought and found that - didn't you ;)?