# How to rewrite before asing for authorization in htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is there a way to redirect to SSL before requiring authentication?  This is my current .htaccess file. The problem is that if you go to the non-SSL site, it will prompt for login, rewrite to https, then prompt again for login.

How can I eliminate the first login and just rewrite first?  I'm using Apache 2.2.29.

I tried what is mentioned in this post without success: [Apache .htaccess redirect to HTTPS before asking for user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/apache-htaccess-redirect-to-https-before-asking-for-user-authentication)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

AuthUserFile /path_to_passwords/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorized personnel only."
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Thanks Jon Lin - I tried adding the lines using the variable "IS_NON_SSL" as shown in the top answer, however I was still prompted twice for login.  There is a comment from Alagappan that might explain why: SERVER_PORT is not an option available in SetEnvIf directive as per the documentation at httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod./mod_setenvif.html#setenvif –   Ramu Mar 20 '14 at 19:18

Answer (score 2):

Uh... how did [the answer in that question that you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15940387/851273) not work?

```
SetEnvIf %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$ IS_NON_SSL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

AuthUserFile /path_to_passwords/.htpasswd
AuthName "Authorized personnel only."
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
Satisfy Any
Allow from env=IS_NON_SSL
```

The *right* way to do this, of course, is to have a completely separate document root setup for non-SSL, and have a single htaccess file there to redirect everything to HTTPS.