# Why isn't redirect done before authentication when using the L-flag?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, redirect, mod-rewrite

For testing purposes, I have a password-protected clone of my website, accessible using a subdomain such as `dev.example.com`. I am using `basic authentication`, and all traffic should be transferred using `https`. Hence, any requests using `http` must be redirected to `https` before authentication. I have tried the following `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite any requests to ip addresses or *.example.com to dev.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(\S*)\s
RewriteRule ^ https://dev.example.com%1 [L,NE,R=302]

# Rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# Require authentication
AuthName "Restricted development environment"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

I'm checking both `%{HTTPS}` and `%{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto}` to support both the case when the client is connecting the server directly, and also the case when the server is behind a load balancer, and the traffic between the load balancer and the server is using `http`.

The idea is that the [`[L]` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) should cause the redirects to happen before authentication, but this does not seem to be the case. When accessing `http://dev.example.com`, authentication pops up. If I enter the credentials correctly, I'm redirected to `https://dev.example.com`, and authentication pops up again.

I found this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267102/apache-htaccess-redirect-to-https-before-asking-for-user-authentication), where the `[L]` flag is not used. The suggested solution there is to set an environment variable when `https` is in use, and only allow access when that variable is set. But I don't understand why I can't just use the `[L]` flag instead. Maybe I've misunderstood it's use and meaning. Why isn't the redirect done before authentication when using the `[L]` flag?

Comment: You have misunderstood `L` flag. `L` flag only acts like `continue` in a loop. It just forces `mod_rewrite` loop to run again. Besides authentication is done using `mod_auth_basic` that is totally independent of `L` flag.

Comment: Thanks, @anubhava. From the documentation: "Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules." To me this sounds like a 302 redirect should be done immediately when a `[L,R=302]`-rule matches, and the auth-section not be reached until after the redirect?

Comment: auth section is from a different module hence `L` flag or any `mod_rewrite` flag won't prevent it from executing. It might also happen that auth section executes first before `mod_rewrite` module.

Comment: Only way these modules communicate with each other is by using env variables in `allow from` or `deny from` directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the different Apache modules work independently, and the `[L]` flag does not prevent authentication from happening, despite the documentation saying  `Use this flag to indicate that the current rule should be applied immediately without considering further rules.`

I ended up with wrapping the authentication in an `If` directive checking that the connection is secure.

If the connection is not secure, authentication is not performed, and the request is redirected. After the redirect, the connection is secure, and authentication is performed.

```
# Require authentication
# If the connection is not secure, authentication is postponed
<If "%{HTTPS} = 'on' || %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} = 'https'">
   AuthName "Restricted development environment"
   AuthType Basic
   AuthUserFile /var/www/html/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
</If>
```

Comment: Wrapping my htpasswd code in this conditional is throwing an error 500 for me.